# Get return statements in a java method

Tags: java

How can I get all possible return values of a method in java?

Example:

```
Object onEvent() {
 if (condition) {
     return "a";
 }

 if (condition2) {
    return "b";
 }

 if (condition3) {
     return "c";
 } 

}
```

I need something like this:

```
String[] returns = Utils.getReturnStatements("object.onEvent()");
returns = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: By "get the return statements" do you really mean "get all possible return `values`"?

Comment: This... really isn't how programming languages work. Except maybe LISP. But Java certainly doesn't have a built-in facility to analyze code structure at runtime.

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do with this?

Comment: I mean, just to begin doing this starting from bytecode, you would need to decompile it into the original AST. (Which is impossible to do accurately, as in you can only get source code that's *equivalent* to the original.)

Comment: @splungebob yes, I need all possible return values.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: I'm developing visual nodes, each one has java code. The node shows the return statements with arrows.

Comment: @iberck: why would you need that? How would you deal with `return random.nextLong()`? That would make 2^63 -1 possible return values.

Comment: @JB Nizet: the returns are alias of possible nodes. For example if you have the nodes: n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 you only can return "n1" or return "n2" ... return "n5".

Comment: So my answer about mapping an entry node to a list of exit nodes makes some sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to analyse simple methods that return constant values such as the one in your example, then you can do this relatively easily via a static analysis using ASM or a similar bytecode toolkit.

For methods matching the structure of your example (i.e that only directly return constants) you just need to look for the pattern

```
LDC ???
ARETURN
```

And collect the constants loaded with LDC. This would be very straightforward.

If the methods can be more complex, e.g if they return values assigned to variables, then you will need to perform a flow analysis. This is much more work, but ASM provides support.

If the methods you are analysing return values other than simple constants then it will be incredibly difficult/impossible to do this via static analysis.

Answer (score 5):

You can **only** retrieve the method signature, which in this case would be `Object` as the return type.

To get the any more details you need to either statically analyze the source code or return a type such as an `enum`.

Comment: are there any library for analyze the source code statically ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do such a thing in Java, but you can do something like this:

```
Object onEvent() {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();    

    if (condition) {
        list.add("a");
    }

    if (condition2) {
        list.add("b");
    }

    if (condition3) {
        list.add("c");
    }

    return list.toArray();

}
```

And then:

```
String[] returns = (String[])MyObj.onEvent();
```

Comment: But then you would test all conditions, even if you were supposed to exit after the first test...

Answer (score 1):

As @Johan said, it is not possible. The only way if you really need it would be for you to store these possible results in a Map mapping the method name to a List or array, or better, use an enum if possible.

Edit:

After reading your comment, I think you should use a HashMap with a Node as the key and a List as value. When you analyse a Node you create the list of exit Nodes in a list, and then map that list to the node.

Answer (score 1):

First remove multiple returns:

Also to get all return types just pass a List of object to your method and change the `onEvent` code like this:

```
Object onEvent(List<Object> rets) {
 String ret = "";
 rets.add("a");
 rets.add("b");
 rets.add("c");

 if (condition) {
     ret = "a";
 }

 if (condition2) {
    ret = "b";
 }

 if (condition3) {
     ret = "c";
 } 
 return ret;
}
```

Make a call to onEvent like this:

```
List<Object> returns = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object retVal = obj.onEvent(returns);
```

Comment: But then you would get the original return wrapped in a list, not all of them, unless youove the add outside of the fors. And it would break the fact that if condition is true, you would still test the other ones...

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes realized and edited. Though I am not really sure if this is a flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

With use of the command pattern and `enum` there is a workaround.

```
public class OnEvent implements Command<EventInfo> {

    @Override
    public EventInfo execute() {
        // do some checking
        return EventInfo.A;
    }

    @Override
    public EventInfo[] getValues() {
        return EventInfo.values();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OnEvent e = new OnEvent();
        EventInfo retVal = e.execute();
        EventInfo[] values = Utils.getReturnStatements(e);
    }

}

enum EventInfo {
    A, B, C;
}

interface Command<TYPE extends Enum<?>> extends KnownReturnValues<TYPE> { public TYPE execute(); }

interface KnownReturnValues<TYPE> { public TYPE[] getValues(); }

class Utils {

    private Utils() {}

    public static <TYPE extends Enum<?>> TYPE[] getReturnStatements(Command<TYPE> c) {
        return c.getValues();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its not really good programming practice, but you can create a class with 3 public data members, and have your code look something like this. (Ill call the class "myclass")

```
public a, b, c = null;

//And then your main class would look something like this
if (condition){
  myclass.a=whatever;
}
else if (condition){
  myclass.b=whatever;
}
else if (condition){
  myclass.c=whatever
 }
```

Then you would need another control structure that said something along the lines of
if (myclass.datamember!=null) to make sure you have values in the class data members.  Again, this is not good programming practice, but it will work for what you want.